# How to change default path in save on close prompt?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to create a template that automatically changes folder suggested by the save prompt to a specified location. I've managed to get it partially working using the following code (modified from [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/SaveInCertainFolder.htm)):

```
Sub FileSave()

Dim UserSaveDialog As Dialog
Set UserSaveDialog = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)

'save changes if doc has been saved previously
If ActiveDocument.Path <> "" Then
ActiveDocument.Save
    Exit Sub
End If

With UserSaveDialog
    .Name = "C:\Users\david\Downloads"
    If .Display Then
        UserSaveDialog.Execute
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Using this code, my macro correctly intercepts the default save behaviour (or Ctrl+S), however it doesn't intercept the save dialog when closing the file. I've tried basically copying this code to a new `Sub` called `Document_BeforeSave`, `FileExit`, `FileCloseEx` and `FileCloseAllEx` (yes, I am having difficulty with all the different objects and what they do :) all to no avail.

I'm not sure the same code will even work in this event, but I don't even get any indication that it has failed to work, so it seems I'm using the wrong event.

Comment: The Word MVP site that you linked to has lots of good information on how to work with the various events. Have you checked it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I somehow missed `AutoClose` ([MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/auto-macros)), which does what I want.